# Calculating the probabilities of a certain random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, statistical-inference

If I have an exponential random variable with a mean of $0.5$ and we consider a sample of length $10$; How can I calculate if its minimum value is bigger than a certain probability or how can I calculate if its maximum value is bigger than a certain probability? How can I approach this?.

*(By exponential variable i assume it refers to that the random variable follows an exponential distribution)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent with the same distribution, say with cdf $F(x)$. Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i \le x\right]
  = \mathbb{P}[X_1 \le x, X_2 \le x, \ldots X_n \le x]
  = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}[X_i \le x]
  = F(x)^n
$$

Can you try a similar trick on the minimum of $X_i$ using $\min \ge x$?

**UPDATE**
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\min_{1 \le i \le n} X_i \ge x\right]
  = \mathbb{P}[X_1 \ge x, X_2 \ge x, \ldots X_n \ge x]
  = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}[X_i \ge x]
  = \left(1-F(x)\right)^n
$$

Now, in general, if $X \sim \mathcal{E}(a)$ then
$$F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-ax} \text{ and } \mathbb{E}[X] = 1/a.$$

Since you know the mean of the distribution, you can compute $a$ and get the actual CDF, and then evaluate at $x = 0.03$...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can do the same just changing the equal signs, but then i get $1-F(X)^n$?. Once i'd be there should i do $F(x)^{10}$ of the exponential distribution to get the results?. I mean; if i have a probability of 0.03 for the first case i should do: $F(0.03)^{10}$?. Why i need the value of the mean then?.

Comment: @user137201 see update

Comment: Thanks. I've seen it very clear and it help me a lot.